# Can I permanently set column visibility in the Content pane of Adobe Bridge CS5?

Tags: software, adobe-bridge

I remove all the columns I don't want visible by right-clicking the column headers and deselecting the column from the list. But when I switch to a different directory of images all the columns are back. They've even reverted in the directory I removed them from...

How do i make my changes stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.  You can right click and choose "Close Column" but they will reappear at the right.  You can set it up as you like it, then create a custom workspace, but guess what, they always come back!

The best you can do is either drag and drop them to the right hand side, out of the way, or "close column" (or uncheck them).

Comment: This has persistently been the case, and nothing I've done has worked. I also asked this question on the [Graphic Design StackExchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/can-i-permanently-set-column-visibility-in-the-content-pane-of-adobe-bridge-cs5), and as mentioned there, I moved to ACDSee Pro and couldn't be more satisfied with that application.